# Array within array when loading from a file

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

My problem is quite peculiar in that I have a solution, but it is in my opinion extremely poor and I am looking for a better one. Here's the problem:

*There's a file that needs to be loaded and have characteristics to create a bunch of objects. The object will have 10-12 properties and there will be a few types of objects each one with different characteristics. To make it even more fun, there's one type of object that is actually made up of two separate other objects, but that can be ignored for the purpose of this question. The file will store the characteristics for a few objects as well as the base class. For example the base class will contain the "car" manufacturer, factory made and maybe  the engine used, but each of the objects will contain other data unique to each model; model name, tires, or whatever you can think of.*

At the moment I have the cars loaded into a map, from the file:

```
std::map<std::string,std::string> loadCars(std::string filePath);
```

This way I can just pass this map to each of the objects constructors and it'll look for the key it needs (For example one model might need to check for the types of sunroof used whilst another doesn't have a sunroof, so can ignore it) and initialize the data. It'll load the car model name into the object name etc, like this:

Car ford = new Car(std::map loadCars(cars.txt);

Now here's the problems, from minor to major:

1) If three car models are loaded in and none of them have sunroofs, the sunroof field in the map will be unitiliazed when its passed to the constructors, I dont know if this will cause errors, so I will require a function that pre-initializes the map with empty values, which I don't think is too bad.

2) And here's the major problem and why this solution does not work:
Some of the values in the car file are arrays. Meaning that an std::string in the map will not store them. Now the solution I have at the moment to me appears very ugly:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> loadCars(std::string);
```

So I pass this map to the constructor and for each of the vectors it has to check if it has more than one value. For example *model name* would not, so it would be hardcoded to put that one value in a string. Or if this particular car only has one type of tire but normally they have multiple types, it'll just put in the vector with one element.

The problem is that when doing the actual file loading absolutely everything will have to be converted from simple strings like the string for the model name into a vector. This seems like a waste and very shoddy code.

Are there any better ways of doing this? Ideally you'd have a map-like container where the second value can either be a vector or a string but I dont think those exist.

Comment: `Car ford = new Car(std::map loadCars(cars.txt);` has unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Yeah, this was all made up code for the purpose of the demonstration, the actual files deal with something a bit more complex.